# Taylor expansion of a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion

Trying to find Taylor series of

$$\frac{z^2}{(1+z)^2}$$

I write it in the form $1- \frac{2}{1+z} + \frac{1}{(1+z)^2}$ and I can find Taylor expansion for each factor, is there another method without decomposing it into two series ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes simply use the expansion of $(1+z)^{\alpha}=1+\alpha z+\frac{\alpha(\alpha-1)}{2!} z^2+\frac{\alpha(\alpha-1)(\alpha-2)}{3!}z^3+\cdots$ and replace $\alpha=-2$. The expression you want to expand is

$$z^2(1+z)^{-2}=z^2(1-2z+3z^2-4z^3+\cdots)$$

Answer (score 1):

Take the Taylor series of $\dfrac{1}{(1+z)^2}$ and then multiply it by $z^2$.

To find the Taylor series of $\dfrac{1}{(1+z)^2}$, notice that its antiderivative is $- \dfrac{1}{1 - (-z)}$, whose power series (using the geometric series) is $-1 + z - z^2 + \dots$. Differentiating this gives the power series for $\dfrac{1}{(1+z)^2}$.